# Get all rows from a specific month and year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a PHP scirpt that is always querying all the data from a database table and it's getting pretty slow. I really just need the data of a specific month and year.

Is there a simple way to get only those entries? For example, everything from February 2013?

The column that stores the dates in my table is of type `datetime`, if that applies to the solution.

Comment: `WHERE date >= '2013-02-01'` *bay-sick-ah-lee!*

Comment: You could partition your table by range (https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/partitioning.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that condition in the WHERE clause of your select statement. I would recommend using BETWEEN operand for two dates:

```
SELECT myColumns
FROM myTable
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-02-28';
```

If you mean to say you want everything beginning with February 2013, you can do so using the greater than or equal to operator:

```
SELECT myColumns
FROM myTable
WHERE dateColumn >= '2013-02-01';
```

**EDIT**

While the above are my preferred methods, I would like to add for completeness that MySQL also offers functions for grabbing specific parts of a date. If you wanted to create a paramaterized query where you could pass in the month and year as integers (instead of a start and end date) you could adjust your query like this:

```
SELECT myColumns
FROM myTable
WHERE MONTH(dateColumn) = 2 AND YEAR(dateColumn) = 2013;
```

Here is a whole bunch of helpful [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: *"For example, everything from February 2013?"* - I think OP is specific as in "starting from" and not between. Therefore, an `>=` would be more fitting.

Comment: Don't get rid of your original answer. Just add to it, in case. Maybe even an `OR` operator. Lot of ways to do this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Lol I didn't. Thanks for your input, that was a good point I just never thought about it that way.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, let's just hope the OP is indexing their table. ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: Thank you, this looks pretty good. But it seems very complicated to convert a month and year into a start and end date automatically. Do you have any advice for this?

Comment: @Forivin I'm not positive what the best way to do it is. If you want an alternative that deals with primitive values, look into the [MONTH() and YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions. You could say something like `WHERE MONTH(dateColumn) = 2 AND YEAR(dateColumn) = 2013`.

Comment: @Forivin no problem, I edited my answer to include that example. Feel free to accept the answer if you use it to solve the problem, or post your own solution if it doesn't.

Comment: I tested it all and it worked perfectly. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should index the datetime field for added efficiency and then use Between syntax in your sql.  This will allow the mysql engine to remove all records that you are not interested in from the returned data set.